# Getting NameError: global name 'open' is not defined in online python tutor?

Tags: python, file, nameerror

I've been sitting at this for hours and I still can't quite solve the error here. I want to open a file and use it in the function 'function_names' but, it appears I can't for whatever reason.

Here's my code.

```
def function_names (file_name):        
    openn = open(file_name, 'r')        
    array_form = openn.readlines()    
    length_array = (len(array_form) - 1)        
    count = 0        
    new_array = [];        
    result = " "        
    while (count <= length_array):            
        point = array_form [count]            
        point = str(point)            
        search =point.rfind('def')            
        end = point.rfind('(')            
        if (search != -1):                
            result = point[4:end]                
            new_array.insert(count, result)             
    count = count + 1        
    return (new_array)    
x = function_names('ex4.py')    
print (x)
```

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: also it always helps to post the full error message that you're getting

Comment: @CameronSparr he's getting a NameError on `open` which is something that should never happen - the Traceback wouldn't be particularily useful in this case, neither is the python version as `open` is part of the language since at least 1.5. OP, the python interpreter you're using seems to block the use of the `open` function, which makes sense for an online interpreter as it would only allow you to open files on the server where the interpreter is running, not on your machine.

Comment: Well as the title says, you are using python online tutor and the web page clearly states *Online Python Tutor supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 with limited module imports and no file I/O*. So this is a current limitation of python online tutor.